# getting error when I am using split method Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Using split method I want to break url and want only image name in input fild  after selecting file from folder. but it showing whole path c:\fackpath\xyz.png

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertFilename()
        {
          var thefile = document.getElementById('thefile').value;
         var x = thefile.toString()
         var y = x.split("\")[0];

         var y = document.getElementById('x').value = thefile;



        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="file" style ="width:90px" id="thefile" onchange="alertFilename()" />
        <input type="text" id ="x" value=""  />
        <p id ="demo"></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

here is I attache [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/WKq1f0iJrgAEJ5wcrpiV?p=preview)

Comment: did you try `split("\\")` ?

Comment: No, I did not try .

Comment: thank you so much it works.

Comment: I didn't understand concept of "\\"

Comment: Your code had a syntax error, it is like this that ` \ ` is an escape character, where your code escaped the `"` character, which ment, you never really closed the string. By writing ` \\ ` you are actually looking for ` \ ` ;) (also in the comments it seems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to write double backslash for right split, because backslash is a special char.

```
var y = x.split("\\")[0];
```